# Lateral gedcom visualisation with embedded pictures

Tags: gedcom, chart-type

I have a large GEDCOM of about 2000 persons from the 1600s until today. From the persons living in the 20th-21th century I have pictures enbedded as hyperlinks in the GEDCOM.

There is a lot of pedigree collapse in the tree since most of the people come from the same village.

Is there a way to visualise the whole tree or at least the 19th-20th-21th century WITH pictures AND Pedigree collapse.

I'm not interested in only ascending of descending tree but more in a lateral tree. I want to show the relationship of the persons in the village.

I seek a python routine or a free solution.

Comment: I remain to be convinced that it is possible to draw up such a network in only 2 dimensions while showing the collapsed pedigree lines without breaks. If breaks are acceptable then it's just a lot of separate trees marked up with "For this person's parents, see..." Seems to me that such a set of trees doesn't really make the collapsed lines clear.

Answer (score 3):

[Family Historian](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/) has a diagram for everyone in your gedcom regardless of how they are related and it copes with pedigree collapse. However, it may not display your images correctly depending on exactly how they are linked in to the gedcom.

With 2000 individuals it may lead to a 'messy' diagram and printing it would, I suspect, be interesting to say the least.

There is a time limited free trial of the programme available so it may well be worth trying it to see if it suits.